# filtering fields based on certain values

Tags: shell, unix

I wish you you all a very happy New Year.

I have a file that looks like this(example): There is no header and this file has about 10000 such rows

```
123 345 676 58 1 
464 222 0 0 1 
555 22 888 555 1 
777 333 676 0 1 
555 444 0 58 1
```

PROBLEM: I only want those rows where both field 3 and 4 have a non zero value i.e. in the above example row 1 & row 3 should be included and rest should be excluded. How can I do this?

The output should look like this:

```
123 345 676 58 1 
555 22 888 555 1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` is perfect for this kind of stuff:

```
awk '$3 && $4' input.txt
```

This will give you the output that you want.

`$3 && $4` is a filter. `$3` is the value of the 3rd field, `$4` is the value of the forth. 0 values will be evaluated as `false`, anything else will be evaluated as `true`. If there can be negative values, than you need to write more precisely:

```
awk '$3 > 0 && $4 > 0' input.txt
```

Comment: Don't even need the `{print}`. `$3 && $4`

Comment: Thank you Janos.. it worked like a charm and I appreciate the detailed explanation.